# How to get the approximated surface area of a one sheeted Hyperboloid

Tags: calculus, geometry

$\frac{x^2}{A^2}+\frac{y^2}{B^2}-\frac{z^2}{C^2}=1$

For ellipsoid, there is an approximated equation for the surface area, is there any approximation for one sheeted Hyperboloid using A, B, and C?

For Ellipsoid,
[image]

I assume the surface area is the outer one and does not include spheres for the top and bottom.

Comment: 1) The **equat**ion must "**equat**e" something ; for example be $\frac{x^2}{A^2}+\frac{y^2}{B^2}-\frac{z^2}{C^2}\color{red}{=1}$ 2) What do you mean by "For ellipsoid, there is an approximated equation for the surface area" ? Please give this equation because the term "surface area" is ambiguous.

Comment: Unfortunately, the hyperboloid has infinite area.